# Formatting an integer to currency value

Tags: mysql

I have tried `CONCAT('$',FORMAT(total, 2))` on an integer column that contains 3-digit numbers such as `500`. The result is `$500.00`, but I want it to be `$5.00`.

It should also work with 4 digit numbers so `1000` would be `$10.00`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `total / 100` instead of `total`.

Comment: To store currency values you would do better to define the column as `DECIMAL (12,2)`. (I use "12" arbitrarily to provide plenty of significant digits.)

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you Gordon!

Comment: Formatting like this should almost always be done in your application layer, not the database. If you can, do it there where localization can be properly applied.